# synchronous buck converter with different MOSFETs

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck, rectifier

do you know if it is possible to use different type of MOSFETs in a syncronous buck converter for the hi-side and the low side switch? How does this improve the converter efficiency?

Thank you

Comment: Yes it is possible. The efficiency and other improvements depend on duty cycle range. In some buck ICs the low side MOSFET has wider channel (lower Rds on) then the upper one. This configuration helps for small duty cycles.

Comment: Thanks, that is a good comment. By the way, I have seen that sometimes the mosfets are both the same (in a synch buck) but their external gate resistor has different values for top and bottom mosfets. I'd like to understand why this is sometimes done in synchronous buck and synchronous boost also... not sure, perhaps I should post a different question. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As one of the comments pointed out it is possible and desirable to use different MOSFETs for some sync buck converters.  Often the duty cycle is low because you're converting from (e.g.) 12V to some much lower voltage like 1.2V.  In that case the duty cycle is 10% (Vout/Vin) and the bottom FET is on 90% of the time.  For that reason you would select a low RDSon device for the bottom FET.  The top FET is only on 10% of the time, but is responsible for most of the switching losses. (The inductor current usually commutates the switch node to just below ground before the bottom FET turns on, making it a ZVS transition.)  So what's important for the top FET is low gate charge and fast switching.  RDSon can be much higher than the bottom FET because it's conducting only 10% of the time.  As the duty cycle changes, these compromises will change accordingly.

There's a method for optimizing these choices called the J/K method (nothing to do with flip-flops.)  You can see it here:

[The J/K Method For FET Selection](http://powerelectronics.com/dc-dc-converters/jk-method-technique-select-optimal-mosfet)

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your answer, I have just a further small question. I am not clear on why the transition where the high MOSFET turns off and the bottom MOSFET turns on is a ZVS... is that because the inductor current is flowing through the body diode of the bottom FET, thus imposing a voltage close to zero across the bottom FET before it turns on? Thanks again

Comment: Yes, in the normal case where the converter is delivering current to the load, the average inductor current is >0.  When the top switch turns off, the inductor current slews the parasitic capacitances on the switch node down below ground until the body diode of the lower FET turns on.  Then after the dead time is complete the bottom FET turns on with only a diode drop across it.